# How do you get to the values of ALL the tokens on your server?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions, remote-notifications

I'd like to get the collection of ALL my FCM user iOS device tokens from this path in my Firebase Database:

```
BootCamp/Notifications/iOS
```

At this location, an autoIDChild is created to store the users' device tokens as *"deviceToken"*.

I've been trying to follow the cloud_functions example at this  [link](http://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js/), but as my use-case is different it's been a little tough to figure out. Here's my cloud-function code in JS:

```
exports.iOSPush = functions.database.ref('/BootCamp/Bulletins/date').onWrite((snapShot, context) =>{

let tokensSnapShot
let tokens

//here, I attempt to get access to all iOS tokens on my server
const getTokens = admin.database().ref('/BootCamp/Notifications/iOS/{key}').once('value');

return Promise.all([getTokens]).then( (results) => {
tokensSnapShot = results[0]
tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapShot)

const payload = {
  notification:{
    title: 'congrats it works',
    body: 'Cloud function noti for ios',
    sound: 'default',
    badge: '1'
    }
};
  //tokens value in the console log is: "node_,ref_,index_". I was expecting an array of tokens:/
  return  admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload)  
})
});
```

How do I get to these iOS tokens on my server?

Answer (score 0):

It finally occurred to me that I had to name the childPath the same as the device token instead of a randomly generated childID.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this example:

```
  return Promise.all([admin.database().ref(`/users/${user}/account/tokensArray`).once('value')]).then(results => {
    const tokens = results[0];
    if (!tokens.hasChildren()) return null;
    let payload = {
      notification: {
        title: 'title',
        body: 'message',
        icon: 'icon-192x192.png'
      }
    };
    const tokensList = Object.keys(tokens.val());
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokensList, payload);
  });
```

Comment: thanks, but I found where I went wrong in trying to firebase's coding sample. I didn't realize 'til late that their database actually saves the tokens as the snapshot key. I went wrong in using an auto generated key.